# PayPal API createInvoice returning always errorId 580001

Tags: php, paypal

Code to invoke PayPal CreateInvoice API. It is always failing says "Invalid Request" and getting errorId 580001. I gone through the code that fills the request and API documention couple of times. No clue what data in Request is wrong.  What could be the wrong in the Request ? Am I missing something here?

```
function getInvoiceAPIHeader()
     {
         global $API_Username, $API_Password, $Signature;

         $API_Username = $this->config['username'];
         $API_Password = $this->config['password'];
         $Signature = $this->config['signature'];


         $headers[0] = "Content-Type: text/namevalue";               // either text/namevalue or text/xml
         $headers[1] = "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID: $API_Username";    //API user
         $headers[2] = "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD: $API_Password";  //API PWD
         $headers[3] = "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE: $Signature";    //API Sig
         $headers[4] = "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID: {$this->APPLICATION_ID}";   //APP ID        
         $headers[6] = "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: ".self::REQUEST_DATA_FORMAT."";   //Set Name Value Request Format
         $headers[7] = "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT: ".self::RESPONSE_DATA_FORMAT.""; //Set Name Value Response Format     

         Debugger::dump($headers);
         return $headers;
     }



function curlRequest($str_req)
 {      
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->end_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $this->getInvoiceAPIHeader());     

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); // tells curl to include headers in response, use for testing   
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);

    // setting the NVP $my_api_str as POST FIELD to curl
    $log_req = $aryRresponse = explode("&", $str_req);
    var_dump($log_req);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $str_req);

    // getting response from server
    $httpResponse = curl_exec($ch);
    //var_dump($httpResponse);

    if(!$httpResponse)
    {
        Debugger::dump("no response");
        $response = "{$this->end_url} failed: ".curl_error($ch)."(".curl_errno($ch).")";
        return $response;
    }

    $aryRresponse = explode("&", $httpResponse);
    var_dump($aryRresponse);
    return $httpResponse;
 }
```

Request dump:

```
array(
    (int) 0 => 'Content-Type: text/namevalue',
    (int) 1 => 'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID: stest_1339339519_biz_api1.paypal.com',
    (int) 2 => 'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD: 1339339539',
    (int) 3 => 'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE: A2I9zTt-d7IIbjVBlzNeLjVm9UJxAPoaKvgzcIz6c6G1-sLSKn5jcI3b',
    (int) 4 => 'X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID: APP-80W284485P519543T',
    (int) 6 => 'X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: NV',
    (int) 7 => 'X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT: NV'
)

array
  0 => string 'invoice.merchantEmail=stest_1339339519_biz%40paypal.com' (length=55)
  1 => string 'invoice.payerEmail=stest_1340973819_per%40paypal.com' (length=52)
  2 => string 'invoice.currencyCode=USD' (length=24)
  3 => string 'invoice.number=PP-99' (length=20)
  4 => string 'invoice.paymentTerms=Net10' (length=26)
  5 => string 'invoice.itemList.item%281%29.name=Coke' (length=38)
  6 => string 'invoice.itemList.item%281%29.description=From+CocaCola' (length=54)
  7 => string 'invoice.itemList.item%281%29.quantity=2' (length=39)
  8 => string 'invoice.itemList.item%281%29.unitPrice=01.65' (length=44)
  9 => string 'invoice.itemList.item%281%29.taxName=Tax1' (length=41)
  10 => string 'invoice.itemList.item%281%29.taxRate=7' (length=38)
```

Response dump:

```
 array
      0 => string 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Date: Mon, 02 Jul 2012 17:06:05 GMT
    Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
    CACHE-CONTROL: no-cache
    X-PAYPAL-MESSAGE-PROTOCOL: NONE
    X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT: NV
    X-EBAY-SOA-REQUEST-ID: 13848a7f-b860-a486-d656-c516ffffc6d8!Invoice!10.72.109.101![]
    X-PAYPAL-OPERATION-NAME: CreateInvoice
    X-PAYPAL-SERVICE-NAME: {http://svcs.paypal.com/types/pt}Invoice
    X-PAYPAL-SERVICE-VERSION: 1.0.0
    X-PAYPAL-ERROR-RESPONSE: TRUE
    Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
    Set-Cookie: Apache=10.72.109.11.13412487648'... (length=679)
      1 => string 'responseEnvelope.ack=Failure' (length=28)
      2 => string 'responseEnvelope.correlationId=4cab848d7c2a0' (length=44)
      3 => string 'responseEnvelope.build=2910623' (length=30)
      4 => string 'error(0).errorId=580001' (length=23)
      5 => string 'error(0).domain=PLATFORM' (length=24)
      6 => string 'error(0).subdomain=Application' (length=30)
      7 => string 'error(0).severity=Error' (length=23)
      8 => string 'error(0).category=Application' (length=29)
      9 => string 'error(0).message=Invalid+request%3A+%7B0%7D' (length=43)
```

What could be the wrong in the Request ? Any Pointers ?

Answer (score 1):

The most common reasons that I've experienced similar errors is:

Not setting `X-PAYPAL-MESSAGE-PROTOCOL` (one-off chance), setting a merchant email/ID, and low transaction amounts.

did notice that your `X-PAYPAL-MESSAGE-PROTOCOL` is set to `FALSE` (potentially a problem)?

they're the best pointers I can give you from the var dump.

Do you have access to a test gateway?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Issue found and able to create invoice now. Issue with items list started with index '1' instead '0'